# Date in string format show two records in advance

Tags: php, mysql

My query is working fine but I wish to show counts of today's date + add 2 more days in advance and order data by today's date followed by tomorrow and day after?

since there are already too many records so the **varchar** row `meeting_date` cannot be changed in another format

Here is MySQL query

date is stored as month/date/year as in 11/01/2016.

```
$today = date("m/d/Y");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM records WHERE meeting = 'Yes' AND (meeting_date LIKE '%".$today."%') ORDER BY id DESC";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
```

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Can you show us the date format?

Comment: date is stored as month/date/year as in 11/01/2016

Comment: whats the date format in your `$today` variable ?

Comment: this is @AshrafulIslamTushar 11/01/2016

Comment: you are geting $today variable data from user side or its fix to today ?

Comment: the today is fixed it displays regualr date not fetching from db or anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this:

```
// get 3 days used in the query
$today = date("m/d/Y");
$day1 =  date("m/d/Y", time() + 86400 ); 
$day2 =  date("m/d/Y", time() + 86400*2 ); 

// updated query without LIKE
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM records WHERE meeting = 'Yes' AND (meeting_date = '$today' OR meeting_date = '$day1' meeting_date = '$day2') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

After you need to sort array with php.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$today = date("m/d/Y");//today's date
$after2days = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+2 days"));//2 days from now
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM records WHERE meeting = 'Yes' AND meeting_date BETWEEN '".$today."' AND '".$after2days."' ORDER BY meeting_date";
```

I'd suggest you to not use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Please use mysqli_* or PDO functions.

Comment: @stweb Yes it would.

Comment: @AJ it did not work i tried and yes i do use PDO but this is an old script too much to change now

Comment: @johrampong Is the date_format same in the database? Like m/d/Y.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in php at the time of getting date

```
$today = date("m/d/Y");
$tommarow= date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+1 days"));
$twoday= date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+2 days"));
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM records WHERE meeting = 'Yes' AND 
(meeting_date = '".$today."' or  meeting_date = '".$tommarow."' or 
meeting_date = '".$twoday."') group by meeting_date ORDER BY meeting_date";
```